# Help - Page.User.Identity gives null("") value when used- IIS 7 and C# 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have my web application running in iis 7 and C# 4.0, I am getting the user identity as null, I need to get the windows username and password. What I need to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the site set up to require windows authentication in web.config.  See here for starters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e.aspx

Then make sure the page you are working on is in a folder that requires authenticated visitors (again web.config)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx

When you say you need to 'get the windows username and password' does that mean you want to retrieve these in your code.  You will not be able to get the password - Windows won't provide that to asp.net.